# I uploaded PHP files into Online File Manager but when I open my domain I can't see them

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, file-manager

I uploaded PHP files into Online File Manager but when I open my domain I can't see them. From my hosting provider I have message :

> Congratulations! Your free hosting account has been activated. You can now use FTP or the file manager in your cPanel to upload your site."

My files are uploaded in htdocs folder. What can be a problem?

Comment: Ask your host....

Comment: Thanks for answer. I sent e-mail yesterday but without answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, you have uploaded PHP file in that folder.
If you are using hostinger like free  server, there will be public_html folder where you should upload.

Another, check if you have index.html or index.php
if not then upload any dummy file with index as name check if dummy file  is coming on opening website

Comment: HI Rupesh, yes I uploaded in that folder, but in mine online file manager there is no public_html folder. I just have htdocs folder and inside of that folder i have index2.html file. Do you know if the problem is with hosting provider?

Comment: do you have index.php file

Comment: Yes I have index2.html and when i clicked i got same message :"Congratulations! Your free hosting account has been activated. You can now use FTP or the file manager in your cPanel to upload your site."

Comment: rename that index2.html as index.html